# Plotting in cloudera pyspark notebook not working

Tags: python, plot, cloudera

I am working with pandas on a cloudera notebook in windows (not jupyter) and I am trying to plot with no luck so far. None of them shows a plot in the notebook as I need it.

I have investigated other answers in the forum and I have found several possible solution but none works for me. Below the solutions I tried:

Solution 1:

```
plt.switch_backend('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['Yes', 'No'],'percentage' : [0.25, 0.75]})

df.plot(kind="pie",subplots=True)
```

results: array([], dtype=object)

Solution 2:

```
plt.switch_backend('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['Yes', 'No'],'percentage' : [0.25, 0.75]})

df.plot(kind="pie",subplots=True)

plt.show()
```

results: Finalized with no errors but no plot

Solution 3:

```
%matplotlib inline 
import pandas as pd
plt.switch_backend('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['Yes', 'No'],'percentage' : [0.25, 0.75]})

df.plot(kind="pie")
```

results: error UnknownMagic: unknown magic command 'matplotlib'

How can I plot directly in the notebook?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: are you using cdsw?

Comment: I don't think I have access to that. I am just using a standard pyspark notebook.

Comment: so jupyter or just terminal? please specify what you mean by "notebook"

Comment: Not jupyter. I added a printscreen to my desciption.

Comment: this is Hue ... it doesn't support magic functions out of the box.  I recommend using jupyter or cdsw if you want to do some python plots via matplotlib ... you can perform some visuals in Hue via Impala SQL ... see this and make sure it matches your Hue version for consistent documentation => https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/hue.html

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. I thought it was my code

Comment: i hope it helps you solve your environment problem ... please consider mark/upvote my comment as "useful"

Comment: done with all your comments

Comment: were you able to solve it?